# R Shiny: Generate HTML Links to Data in A Column When Using `FluidRow()`

Tags: r, shiny

I am displaying tabular data using the R package Shiny. I'd like to have the values in one column presented as HTML links that can be used to navigate to another page.

How do I do this?

Paul K

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example to show what you have already tried and so it's easier for others to understand your problem and help you.

Comment: Well, to my best understanding there is nothing to try because the data is presented on a single row e.g. `fluidRow(dataTableOutput(outputId="table"))`. So I'm wondering if there is a way that can expose the internals of this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of your columns has links, you could add HTML link tags to it and display it in your datatable:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  #create dummy data
  data <- data.frame(links=c("http://www.google.com","http://www.google.com"))
  #add html link tags
  data$links <- paste0("<a href='",data$links,"'>",data$links,"</a>")

  #render datatable
  output$table <- renderDataTable(data,escape=FALSE)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(dataTableOutput(outputId="table"))
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You need the `escape=FALSE` in the `renderDataTable` because with shiny 0.11 HTML entities are escaped, from [here](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/shiny/NEWS)

```
Added an `escape` argument to `renderDataTable()` to escape the HTML entities
  in the data table for security reasons. This might break tables from previous
  versions of shiny that use raw HTML in the table content, and the old behavior
  can be brought back by `escape = FALSE` if you are aware of the security
  implications. (#627)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. It worked but I had to ensure that the data was imported with the separator clearly defined (sep="\t") so that the `<a href=...` was not treated as two columns (`<a` and `href=...`).